# Laravel testing

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit

In my Laravel package package I'm testing an api endpoint, but I **always** get
a 404 response!?!?

Here is the file (see `unsuccessfulLogin` method):

https://github.com/larsjanssen6/underconstruction/blob/master/tests/Integration/UnderConstructionModeTest.php

```
$this->post('/under/check', ['code' => 1235]);
```

In my service provider:

https://github.com/larsjanssen6/underconstruction/blob/master/src/UnderConstructionServiceProvider.php

```
  $routeConfig = [
            'namespace'  => 'LarsJanssen\UnderConstruction\Controllers',
            'prefix'     => 'under',
            'middleware' => [
                'web',
            ],
        ];
        $this->getRouter()->group($routeConfig, function ($router) {
            $router->post('check', [
                'uses' => 'CodeController@check',
                'as'   => 'underconstruction.check',
            ]);
            $router->get('construction', [
                'uses' => 'CodeController@index',
                'as'   => 'underconstruction.index',
            ]);
            $router->get('js', [
                'uses' => 'AssetController@js',
                'as'   => 'underconstruction.js',
            ]);
        });
```

I register these routes! And in postman it's working. So why is it not working in my test?

Comment: Is this a problem specific with the package ? Do the standard laravel routes work?

Comment: Yes, when I check ```php artisan route:list``` the routes are there. The application is working perfectly but the test not...

Comment: artisan commands usually run in a different environment than tests. Try testing the laravel home route

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `$this->post()`? Should it be `$this->get()`?